# index out of bound with iterrows

Tags: python, pandas, indexoutofboundsexception

I got error IndexError: index 5105 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5105
with that code i understand the problem but how to solve it knowing that i use df.iterrows() ?

```
anime_edges = {}
for idx, row in interactions_from_selected_users_df.iterrows():
    similar_indices = anime_interactions[idx].argsort()[:-100:-1]
    similar_items = [(anime_interactions[idx][i], interactions_from_selected_users_df['anime_id'][i]) for i in similar_indices]
    anime_edges[row['anime_id']] = similar_items[:20]
```

the main purpose of this code is to create the edges of one node with other most similar nodes (i try to build a graph based recommender)

anime_interactions come from dot product of embedding matrix through linear_kernel

```
anime_interactions = linear_kernel(anime_embeddings, anime_embeddings)
```

Comment: yes, but error come from the third line similar_indices = anime_interactions[idx].argsort()[:-100:-1]

Comment: Is it possible that `anime_interactions` has fewer elements in it than `interactions_from_selected_users_df`?

Comment: [i] come from list comprehension --> for i in similar_indices

Comment: anime_interactions has 5105 elements in it, interactions_from_selected_users_df has 7264 do you think problem is there ?

Comment: Yes - you are using `idx` to index into `anime_interactions`, that will fail when you get past 5105

Comment: I get it, i'll inspect my dataframe to solve the problem, thanks.

Comment: I moved my comment into an answer.  Feel free to either close the question entirely, or mark the answer as accepted - that will signal to others that this issue has been answered.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `iterrows()` loop iterates over each row in `interactions_from_selected_users_df` with `idx` as an index placeholder.  But you use `idx` to index into `anime_interactions` as well.

Per your comments, there are more rows in `interactions_from_selected_users_df` than in `anime_interactions`, so you will see the error you are getting when `idx` is larger than the number of rows (5105) in `anime_interactions`.

You can use conditional logic or `try`/`except` inside your loop to catch these errors - or just stop when `idx == len(anime_interactions)`.